# Git actions and GitHub actions counted as different users

Tags: git, github, git-commit

For some reason, whenever I make a commit via my git terminal, it is counted as my real name. Whenever I make a commit via the GitHub user interface, it is counted as my GitHub profile. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user your terminal commits as you configure yourself with:

```bash
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```

Then when you push your commits GitHub checks the email address against the list of [email addresses you have on your account](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account), and if they match GitHub displays the commit as coming from your account.

To see which email address made a commit on your local machine, simply do

```bash
git log
```

Comment: You can add your commit email address to your github profile. That way GitHub will see them as the same,